# Is there ANY way to see chrome iOS CSS?

Tags: html, ios, css, google-chrome, responsive-design

So, I'm building responsive pages using the Chrome dev tools iOS emulator, only to find that there's a 5% difference when you check it out on an actual phone.

All my css is normalized and has the latest vendor prefixes, so I'm stuck with *guessing* what's going wrong with that last 5%.

Surely there is a way to see the CSS output on a mobile device? Dev-tools for mobile. Surely!

Comment: What do you mean by 5% difference? How are you measuring that? It's likely that you're using CSS which isn't compatible with Safari.

Comment: 5% was just a human guess. The point is — there are are some things that don't match between the emulator and the real mobile browser and I can't figure out how to see the mobile browser css... I will re-check the vendor prefixes but I was hoping there's a way to look "under the hood" on an iphone.

Answer (score 3):

On Android phones, Chrome does support [Remote Debugging](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging) over USB

Since you're in iOS, though, you are able to use Safari's remote debugging feature to try to debug the page. Chrome for iOS [uses Apple's UIWebView](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/ios/overview) to render pages, so debugging in iOS Safari should give you the same results you're seeing in iOS Chrome.

Safari's remote debugging feature can be used by going to `Settings > Safari > Advanced` on your device, connecting the device to the computer via USB, then in Safari on your Mac, go to `Develop > [Device] > [website]` to debug.

Comment: @DavidThomas you're right, I didn't take into account he was asking specifically about iOS chrome. I edited my answer to try be more helpful

Comment: Thank you! I've deleted my earlier comment - since it's no longer relevant - and removed my down-vote.

Comment: "debugging in iOS Safari should give you the same results you're seeing in iOS Chrome" - That's unfortunately not true. I had a case where Chrome would be rendering a page a bit differently (CSS) than Safari on iOS.